# Coroutine equivalent of Flowable.mergeDelayError

Tags: rx-java, coroutine

I'm in the middle of migrating Rxjava based project to Coroutine Flow.
I need to merge multiple api calls and if one of them fails, I still want it to proceed and do the job.
Here's the original code.

```kotlin
fun requestHomeDataAtOnce() {
    val requestList = mutableListOf(
        requestTab1(),
        requestTab2(),
        requestTab3(),
        requestTab4()
    )
    requestHome(requestList = requestList)
}

private fun requestHome(requestList: MutableList<Single<out Result<Any>>>) {
    val responseList: MutableList<Any?> = mutableListOf()
    Single.mergeDelayError<Any>(requestList)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(), true)
        .subscribe({
            //.. do something
    })
    //..
}
```

So I noticed that `mergeDelayError` will run merged sources and delay any error.
My question is, should I use Flow `combine` or `flattenMerge` in this case?
I'm still trying to grasp the basic concept of it.

Comment: I don't have much experience with the Flow api, but generally, merge == fromIterable + flatMap, thus you'd have to turn that requestList into a Flow (asFlow?), then call flattenMerge. However, I can't find any documentation regarding delaying the error other than suppressing it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this code and it works for now.

```kotlin
private fun requestMergedData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        merge(
            repository.requestPopularStream(),
            repository.requestPlanShopStream()
        ).onEach {
            it.fold(
                onSuccess = { data ->
                    (data as? SearchPopularResponse)?.let { popular ->
                        popularData = popular
                    }
                    (data as? SearchPlanShopResponse)?.let { planShop ->
                        planShopData = planShop
                    }
                },
                onFailure = {}
            )
        }.onCompletion {
            setModules()
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```